# Does IOS NFC support Bank Card reading

Tags: ios, nfc

I want to develop a demo app can read contactless bank card (like VISA MasterCard),does IOS support it ?Apple Development Spec. says "Core NFC doesn't support payment-related Application IDs.", what's that mean?

Comment: I guess Apple has some security concerns with reading credit cards via NFC.

Answer (score 3):

When a device attempts to read a contactless card, the first thing it does is tell the card to load a specific application (i.e. the VISA payment application).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EMV#Application_selection

What Apple are saying is it does not support that.

Apple Pay is the only thing that can do anything relating to contactless payments.